# Why is my bootstrap not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me! Why is bootstrap not loading the classes?

Here's my code which is just a table and a simple button, yet no classes are applied

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </title>
</head>
<body>

<table class="table" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>TX ID CxPay</th>
            <th>TX ID IY</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>1asas</td>
            <td>1asas</td>
            <td>1asas</td>
            <td>1asas</td>
            <td>1asas</td>
            <td>1asas</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-success">asasa</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable();
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Neither bootstrap nor datatables is working. What am I missing here?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid throwing out the computer is the only choice, yes.

Answer (score 4):

You are importing the script inside `<title>` that's not correct. In `<title>` only text is allowed describing your page's title. Place your `<script>` and `<link>` above the `</head>`

Answer (score 2):

All your included files are in your `<title>`.
You have to write :

```
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
```