# Bootstrap Tooltip Not Working: How to fix from 4.3 Upgrade?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I converted to Bootstrap 4 and for some reason Bootstrap Tooltip is not working below. How would I resolve issue? I followed directions from website here.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="toolset">
  <a class="toolsettooltip" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" title="Delete">
    <button class="mdc-button toolsetbutton delete">
      <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon toolsetbutton">delete</i>
    </button>
  </a>
<a class="toolsettooltip" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" title="Notification">
  <button class="mdc-button toolsetbutton notification">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon toolsetbutton">notifications
    </i></button>
  </a>
</div>

<script>$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});</script>
```

Similar Question: [Why is my Bootstrap code not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649246/why-is-my-bootstrap-code-not-working)

[Why is my bootstrap not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690931/why-is-my-bootstrap-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import Bootstrap's CSS styles in addition to the javascript. Other than that, the code you posted is working fine.

For the version you're using, that would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

See the [Getting Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) section of Bootstrap's documentation for more info.